# Android studio exisiting project throwing error on startup

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been working on a project lately.
Yesterday my laptop shut down all of a sudden and I didn't bothered to start it again.

Today when I started the project, I saw that after my gradle build, I have my MainActivity full of errors. Wonder what's wrong! When I try to debug and run the project it runs fine. Everything from import to all the System.out.println has error in it.

When I try to print out something on EditText listner and then run the project. the project works fine.

Additionally there was a file called maniac~2.jav that was auto-created with the same content as that of MainActivity.

Need help in this
Thanks in advance

Here's the screenshot of the error
[image]

**EDIT**
My gradle console messages on building the project

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.325 secs
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 10.903 secs
```

Comment: What's the exact error ? Have you tried Build -> Rebuild Project ? You can see error messages in the EventLog tab in bottom right.

Comment: Well I tired that, I cleaned and also rebuild my project. But the error stays. And as I said, I just checked running and debugging the project. Surprisingly it runs even after so many errors.

Comment: It would help if you share the error messages from "Messages" or "EventLog" tab.

Comment: @SlowAndSteady check the edit section, I have updated the messages on build, event log too just says executing tasks and gradle build finished

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a few workarounds to overcome this issue :

1- Choose File --> Invalidate Cache and Restart

2- Change the compileSdkVersion in your build.gradle file, to a different version and Choose Build Project.

3- Change the buildTools version of the project and try to rebuild the project.

4- Delete the outputs and temp folders in the app/build and rebuild the project.

Comment: Okay, So tried the first 3 points. The first one worked for me. Now my project is without any errors. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.